# undefined method `completed_at' for 2012-08-03 20:24:48 UTC:Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, activesupport

Here's the error message and its application trace:

```
NoMethodError in Shopping::OrdersController#index

(the root of error is the application directory.)
undefined method `completed_at' for 2012-08-03 20:24:48 UTC:Time

app/models/coupon.rb:44:in `eligible?'
app/models/coupon.rb:40:in `qualified?'
app/models/coupon.rb:34:in `value'
app/models/order.rb:276:in `coupon_amount'
app/models/order.rb:260:in `find_total'
app/models/order.rb:284:in `credited_total'
app/controllers/shopping/orders_controller.rb:100:in `form_info'
app/controllers/shopping/orders_controller.rb:21:in `index'
```

However, when I select to see full trace, the first line is

```
activesupport (3.2.7) lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:328:in `method_missing'
```

I'm not sure if it's the controller's problem or active_support's problem. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

In coupon.rb

```
def qualified?(item_prices, order, at = nil)
  at ||= order.completed_at || Time.zone.now
  item_prices.sum > minimum_value && eligible?(at)
end

def eligible?(order, at = nil)
  at ||= order.completed_at || Time.zone.now
  starts_at <= at && expires_at >= at
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without any context to the error, its really hard to help you out man.

Comment: The problem is in your coupon.rb L44 method eligible? (see stack trace). You're probably calling "completed_at" on the incorrect object.

Comment: Yes, this error only occurs when I use coupon. I have added method qualified and eligible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 44 of `coupon.rb` you are calling `completed_at` on a `Time` object. I don't know which line this is from your code, but that should be enough to get you through.